# cannot debug Solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I created a SharePoint solution using visual studio and attached it to the w3wp.exe process. I cannot debug although I have put many breakpoints all around the code. I am running Visual studio as administrator as well.

Comment: Did you build the solution in Release? If so, there is your problem

Comment: try rebuilding, redeploying the DLL, iis reset. and when you attach it to a process, tick both checkboxes and click refresh, then attach it to all w3wp.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can think, there can be 3 reasons.

1. SharePoint might run under different user. So check all processes from all users and attach to all w3wp.exe processes.
2. You could have made a Sandboxed Solution. In that case, it should be attached to SPUCWorkerProcess.
3. You could be debugging a timerjob. In case, that should be attached to OWSTIMER.exe process.

Comment: Thank you I have chosen sandboxed solution. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

1.Attach to all the w3wp process or in webcofig

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

Comment: It was sandbox solution option selected. Thank you.